# How to create a nested loop to check if a value exists in a second list

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare values in two lists. I want my code to compare a value in the first list and check all the entries in the second list. If there is a match then the code will print true next to the value in the first list and if not it will print false.

The problem I am having is that my code only compares values that are in the same row.

The code runs and I have tried it on a two smaller lists to make sure the data types are to same and there aren't any extra spaces or commas in the lists that would lead to a "False" output. I have also tried changing the order of the for and if statements but this doesn't work either.

```
Sub findvalues()
    For i = 2 To 16
        For j = 2 To 16
            If Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value Then
                Cells(i, 4).Value = "TRUE"
            ElseIf Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(j + 1, 1).Value Then
                Cells(i, 4).Value = "TRUE"
            Else
                Cells(i, 4).Value = "FALSE"
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

[Here are the two lists I am testing the code on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP3BF.png)

Comment: Is there any reason why you couldn’t just use formulas on the sheet? Like MATCH or VLOOKUP?

Comment: Yes the VLOOKUP formula seems to be producing a similar result as the code above - ie saying that the values don't exist (N/A)

Comment: Get rid of the #N/A!s by wrapping it in IFERROR function?

Comment: If you have problems with spaces and similar you can use `TRIM` function

Comment: @simon_innes95 do you specify FALSE as the last argument in the VLOOKUP parameters? A screenshot of both datasets would be useful.

Comment: The problem with your code is that for the first list scan it correctly marks if a value exists in the list or not, but then in the second loop you override those values and keep only the results for the second entry (this goes on and on). I would bet that the result of that `Sub` is the results of checking the last entry in your list

Comment: @Skin Yes I do. I know that there are excel formulas to use but this is more of an exercise for me as I have just started python, and VBA for my work.

Comment: @simon_innes95 oh fair enough then. Welcome to the magical world of VBA then. The most disliked programming language on Stackoverflow!  :-)

Comment: @RCaetano How would I correct this? I added a picture of the data set I am using and the output.

Comment: @Skin I added the data set and output above. Yes I agree I am enjoying using python much more at the moment!

Comment: You’re testing on columns 1 & 5, should you not be testing on columns 1 & 3?

Comment: @Skin Ah yes sorry, that is my older code for the original data set, I will update the code about. I was using 1 & 3 for the data set I have added.

Comment: One question: will you have duplicate entries in your lists? Let's say in first list having a 2, 3, 4, 2

Comment: @RCaetano Yes potentially but I have not catered for that. I would like to know how to :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many was to achieve that. one of them is by using **IF** & **COUNTIF**

**Formula**

```
=IF(COUNTIF($E$2:$E$6,A2)>0,"TRUE","FALSE")
```

Results:

[image]

**VBA CODE**

```
Option Explicit

Sub findvalues()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change if needed

        Set rng = .Range("A2:A130") 'set rng to includes values from column A, rows 2:130

        For i = 2 To 130 'Loop from row 2 to 130
            'Check if the values in column C includes in the rng
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, .Range("C" & i).Value) > 0 Then
                .Range("D" & i).Value = "TRUE"
            Else
                .Range("D" & i).Value = "FALSE"
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to use the code above as an exercise :) I am aware of the formulas available

Comment: I have tried this but I get a run-time error 9 "subscript out of range". I am also confused by "set rng to includes values from column D, rows 2:130". Do you mean I must change the range from ("C2:C16") to ("C2:D130")? Would you also mind explaining your for loop? I am really very new to this and while i generally get the idea I would like to know exactly why you are doing the above...

Comment: I sorted out the error, I was referencing the wrong sheet. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: I have just been testing the code on my actual lists that need to be compared and while the code runs it does not return the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Slight mods to your code based on the data you provided in columns 1 & 3.  As always, things could be improved but this should get you going ...

```
Sub findvalues()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, bResult As Boolean

    For i = 2 To 16
        strValueToLookFor = Cells(i, 1)

        For j = 2 To 16
            bResult = False

            If strValueToLookFor = Cells(j, 3).Value Then
                bResult = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j

        Cells(i, 6).Value = bResult
    Next i
End Sub
```

... you may just need to flick the columns over so the first list searches on the second list or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any need for VBA - formulas are the way to go - but to avoid two loops one could do this:

```
Sub findvalues()

Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To 130
    Cells(i, 4).Value = IsNumeric(Application.Match(Cells(i, 1).Value, Range("C2:C130"), 0))
Next i

End Sub
```

Update: this does not cater for multiple matches.

Answer (score 0):

VBA code to reconcile two lists.

```
 Sub Reconciliation()
Dim endRow As Long
Dim ICount As Long
Dim Match1() As Variant
Dim Match2() As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Recon")
ICount = 0
endRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
endRow1 = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row
Match1 = Sheet1.Range("b2:b" & endRow)
Match2 = Sheet1.Range("K2:K" & endRow1)

For i = LBound(Match1) To UBound(Match1)
For j = LBound(Match2) To UBound(Match2)
    If Match1(i, 1) = Match2(j, 1) Then
    ICount = ICount + 1
        Sheet1.Range("C" & i + 1).Value = ICount
        Sheet1.Range("L" & j + 1).Value = ICount
    Else

   End If
   Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried this code and it runs but there is no output... I have some questions though as I don't understand all of what you are saying due to my lack of experience. In line "endRow = ws.Cells(s.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row" I understand you are defining the end of the list correct, however what does the "2" refer to? and the "11" in the line below?

Comment: However when I modify the column numbers I still have the same problem as before... no TRUE or FALSE printing